# IP-over-IP tunnels - necessary to limit source IPs?

Tags: security, tunnel

I am using simple IPIP Tunnels on Centos 5 between my hosts, without IPSec or similar, using encryption on the application layer.  I would like to know, if I should add additional precautions regarding the origin of the tunnel packets.

In other words: If there was a way in `iptables`, would it make sense to add a rule that only accepted tunneled packets from a predefined list of external IPs?  Or does the IPIP tunnel make sure itself that the packet is coming from the peer where it is supposed to send back the answer?

And if such filtering would be advisable, how could I do it, `iptables` seems to see only the inner address.  Could I do it with `ebtables` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does the IPIP tunnel make sure itself that the packet is coming from the peer where it is supposed to send back the answer?

Of course yes, otherwise, you would not be able to have multiple IPIP tunnels to different peers.

But this can only happens if you have actually specified the address of the peer on the ipip interface. But you did, right ?

If you also specify the local address to be used by the tunnel, the kernel will also check it.

Answer (score 2):

Iptables can filter ip protocol. 
You should use protocols 4 and 94 (https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) 
In order to use the protocol in an Iptables rule use the option -p.
For example: iptables -A INPUT -p 4 --source-port 10.10.10.1 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p 94 --source-port 10.10.10.1 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

ebtables is used if you have a bridge of interfaces and the frames are not captured by iptables (which I believe is not your case).